# Unable to perform Mouseover and click in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to perform mouseover function on an element using selenium webdriver in java. The code I am using is:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[@title='Directory'][.='People']"));
actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).build().perform();
WebElement subLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='peopleSubmenu']/ul/li[1]/a"));
subLink.click();
```

But the code is not working when the mouse is moved. Please suggest me some solution

Comment: What happens when you run this code. Also post the HTML content.

Comment: Remove the `.` at the beginning of the xpaths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this, just another form of what vignesh posted below

```
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(menuHoverLink).perform();
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(subLink).perform();
subLink.click();
```

Comment: @VarshaJawale what exception are you getting? at which line?

Comment: I am not getting any exception but the mouseover lasts only for a few seconds.

Comment: Give a try by including Thread.sleep for 1000ms in between mouse over and clicking.

Comment: wait is not an issue here.. I have tried by inserting wait

Comment: So what was the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Intead of clicking on the sublink directly, do mouseover on sublink and click it,

```
actions.moveToElement(subLink).click().build().perform();
```

Edit: Noticing singe31 comment, Remove the .(dot) in the sublink xpath,

```
WebElement subLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='peopleSubmenu']/ul/li[1]/a"));
```

Comment: I am able to perform mouseover when the mouse cursor is not on the browser screen. It the cursor is moved, the mouseover lasts jst for a fraction of second. I want to perform mouseover even if the mouse is moved.

Comment: "I want to perform mouseover even if the mouse is moved." what is it mean? btw have you corrected the xpath as suggested?